# Azure AD B2C example fail to compile for .Net Core 2.0

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, asp.net-core-2.0

I used this sample https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnetcore-webapp for my .net core 1.1 web app. Now, I've been trying to make it work myself for .NET Core 2.0 but had no luck, too much unclear things in all this.

So, can anyone provide an example of how to use Azure AD B2C with ASP.Net Core 2.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A new branch was created with the version upgrade. It's a community submission and not yet tested by the product team but check it out: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnetcore-webapp/tree/core2.0

Comment: The specified link above is broken.